# Sharepoint JScript if statement not executing

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a javascript for a Sharepoint site to show and hide fields based on values in drop down boxes.  My second If statement works fine but for some reason the first is not working.  Can anyone see if I am missing a simple syntax error.  Spent two days on this and I think a fresh set of eyes will help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Get a single select dropdown field
var SubTypeField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Sub Type');
var IssueTypeField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Issue Type');


// create a function to show or hide Field based on Drop Down values value
var showOrHideField = function() {
    var SubTypeFieldValue = SubTypeField.GetValue();
    var IssueFieldValue = IssueTypeField.GetValue();

    // Hide the field if the selected value is Ergonomic
    if (SubTypeFieldValue === 'Ergonomic'){
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Other Description');
    }
    else {
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Other Description');
    }

    if(IssueFieldValue === 'Incident'|| IssueFieldValue === 'Close Call'|| IssueFieldValue === 'Observation') {
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Type of injury sustained');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Cause of lost time/injury or first aid');
        SPUtility.HideSPField('Was medical treatment necessary');
        SPUtility.GetSPField('Type of injury sustained').SetValue('');
        SPUtility.GetSPField('Cause of lost time/injury or first aid').SetValue('');
        SPUtility.GetSPField('Was medical treatment necessary').SetValue('No');
    }
    else {
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Type of injury sustained');
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Cause of lost time/injury or first aid');
        SPUtility.ShowSPField('Was medical treatment necessary');
    }


};

// run at startup (for edit form)
showOrHideField();

// make sure if the user changes the value we handle it
$(IssueTypeField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
$(SubTypeField.Dropdown).on('change', showOrHideField);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with my code.  In SharePoint you have to make a reference to a file in your document library.  For testing reasons I renamed the working one to play with the new file I had created, listed in my question.  SharePoint automatically renames the file reference for you.  So I was continually updating a file thinking my code is wrong while I just needed to change the reference to point to the new file.  Any questions about my explanation let me know as this may help others down the road

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to log the values of the Fields you are trying to hide?

Use `console.log()` to log the values. Also the field names seem weird... I usually work with jQuery and not SPUtility.

Be sure to check, if SubTypeField and IssueTypeField are initialized correctly. 
Maybe it helps to move the declaration into an init function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// Get a single select dropdown field
  var SubTypeField;
  var IssueTypeField;
  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(init);
});
function init() {
  SubTypeField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Sub Type');
  IssueTypeField = SPUtility.GetSPField('Issue Type');
}
```